# What variables can be used in Pspad in a link?

Tags: pspad

I know about %File% and %Line%... What else do you know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found these.
%File%
%Dir%
%DosFile%
%DosDir%
%Name%
%Ext%
%ProjectName%
%PSPath%
%URLFile%
%HTTPFile%
%SelText%
%Input%
%Word%
%AppData%
%HomePath%
%Temp%
%UserProfile%
%AllUsersProfile%
%WinDir%
%Line%
They can be used as command line arguments in Links\Tools  section.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about command-line arguments for starting PSPad, they are listed in the [online PSPad documentation](http://gogogadgetscott.info/pspad/commandline.htm).  If not, can you provide a bit more information on what you're trying to do?

Comment: no, I am not asking about command line arguments.

Comment: @Aftershock: And yet in your self-answering post, you state "They can be used as command line arguments in Links\Tools section."  And I still don't know for sure what you *were* asking.  For future reference: clarity is important.